# Anaconda Jupyter Notebook / OpenCV cannot play mp4 files

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

i cannot open or play any mp4 files that i uploaded on jupyter notebook. Beside that i cannot open any files with opencv. Here its an example code:

```
doc = cv2.VideoCapture("hero.mp4") #just a name of mp4 file that i uploaded on notebook

if cap.isOpened() == False:
  print("the video cannot opened!")

while cap.isOpened() == True:
  ret,frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True:
    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
       if waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("b"):
          break
  else:
    break
    
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried to open any video file using opencv on Jupyter notebook. But when i run this code the output is " The video cannot opened! "

Could y'all help me?

Thanks.

Comment: (1) `assert os.path.exists("hero.mp4")` (2) `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())`

Comment: and... is this a local jupyter instance, or is this google colab, or something else?